# Auto submit the user registration form

Tags: forms

I am customizing the user registration in the template file. I want to auto submit the registration form using Drupal code, or JavaScript code.

Does anyone know how I should achieve this?

Comment: Click the button says "Create New Account". Its simple. `;)`

Comment: Please make sure you add in the research you've already done yourself; what you tried, what didn't work, what errors you received, etc. It isn't appropriate to ask for what essentially would be a full tutorial on a Stack Exchange site :)

Comment: What do you mean by auto submit ?

Comment: i have the fields which is filled with random values in the registration form using java script and i want to submit the form programmatically using any scripts or code.

Comment: Why do you want to by pass this form? Are you trying to create mock users for testing? If so look at devel generate.

Comment: @Dhinesh.ES then this is not really a Drupal question but a javascript question. https://www.google.com/search?q=how+to+use+javascript+to+submit+a+form&oq=how+to+use+javascript+to+submit+a+form&aqs=chrome.0.57j62l3.4132&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#hl=en&tbo=d&sclient=psy-ab&q=how+to+submit+a+form+in+javascript&oq=how+to+submit+a+form&gs_l=serp.3.1.0i7j0j0i7l2.6430.6430.0.7857.1.1.0.0.0.0.67.67.1.1.0.les%3B..0.0...1c.1.z45q4dmTH0o&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.&fp=2a345dc0adc14ebe&bpcl=38897761&biw=1680&bih=929

Comment: @charlie and clive - yes you guys are correct , the question here i asked is not a formal drupal question , but while we customizing the tpl page we should consider the drupal standard code and the script based on that ,hope you guys knew that.if its purely javascript then i can with google so and so,i already tried with javascript and jquery stuffs..thanks for reply..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your question, I would recommend you use the [devel module](http://drupal.org/project/devel) to auto-generate random users.

OR if you really want to auto-submit the user form (or any form) then attach JavaScript to the page that does so via [#attached](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7#attached) in a [hook_form_alter](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7) or via [drupal_add_js()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/drupal_add_js/7) or simply in your theme via a .js file included in your .info file.

The javascript would be as Eugene Fidelin has posted above – `$('#user-register-form').submit();`or potentially by extending the Drupal.behaviors object, which is recommended for a number of reasons I won't get into here:

```
(function ($) {

  Drupal.behaviors.myModule = {
    attach: function (context) {
      $('#user-register-form').submit();
    }
  };

})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 0):

To submit user register form use following code:

```
$('#user-register-form').submit();
```